# Want Outlook rule for "sent to" in CC box

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

I want to make a rule for when emails are sent to specific users/groups IN THE CC BOX.  The "sent to" conditional appears to only pick up emails when the users/groups are in the TO BOX.  Also, I can only see a rule for the CC field for MY NAME, e.g. "where my name is in the Cc box".

**UPDATE**
I've searched the internet for a couple of days and haven't found a solution.

I've created a rule that works fine if the users/groups are in the TO BOX but the "sent to" clause doesn't catch emails that CC my Group_I_Am_In.

- From [me](http://mailto:me)
- and sent to [Group_I_Am_In](http://mailto:Group_I_Am_In)
- move it to the [Stuff_From_Me_To_My_Group](http://mailto:Stuff_From_Me_To_My_Group) folder

Is there something equivalent I can do when my Group is in the CC box?

Help?

Comment: Hi Eddie, and welcome to Superuser. It's a good start for a question, but I don't really know if you already looked into solutions for this on-line. To prevent that people will provide you with answers that you already tried (and didn't work for you), could you please include your own research and indicate what you've already tried?

Comment: currently, outlook seems to only have option to filter email that are cc or bcc to your own address.  You can visit the Outlook user voice forum: https://outlook.uservoice.com/ to vote for a similar idea or post your own feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a rule **with specific words in the message header** and specify the necessary email addresses there.

For example:

[image: Outlook Rules Wizard]